# Fraction Equation problem

Tags: math-mode, align, amsmath

I am a new user of LaTeX. I am using `amsmath` package but keep getting errors with the following:

```
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial P}{\partial t} = \mu(N,I)P - mP - \nu \frac{\partial P}{\partial z} + \kappa   \frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial z^2} 
\end{align}
```

and the error message:

> Package amsmath Error: Erroneous nesting of equation structure.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe you have `\begin{align}...\end{align}` inside an `equation` environment, which is wrong. Please make a small but complete example that shows the error.

Comment: `align` really shouldn't be used for one-line displays.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

(Too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer.)

The code snippet you posted isn't compilable by itself. In order to reproduce the error message you report, I had to augment it as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align' environment
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial P}{\partial t} = 
  \mu(N,I)P - mP - \nu \frac{\partial P}{\partial z} 
  + \kappa\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial z^2} 
\end{align}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

When I try to run this code, I get the following error message:

```
! Package amsmath Error: Erroneous nesting of equation structures;
(amsmath)                trying to recover with `aligned'.

See the amsmath package documentation for explanation.
```

The moral of the story: Do *not* nest `equation` and `align` environments. Use the former environment for single-line display-style equations, and employ the latter for multi-line display-style equations.

Finally, the following code compiles without an error message. Observe that I use an `equation` environment since we're dealing with a single-line equation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial P}{\partial t} = 
  \mu(N,I)P - mP - \nu \frac{\partial P}{\partial z} 
  + \kappa\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial z^2} 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```